# How to Map result from db

Tags: list, flutter, sqlite, dictionary, dart

So as we know rawQuery from Sqlite returning <List<Map<String, Object?>>>.

I need data in this form :

```
//example

Map<String, List> _dataItems = {
  '1st ': ['Name01', 'SubData01'],
  '2th': ['Name02', 'SubData02'],
  '3th': ['Name03', 'SubData03'], 
};
```

IM trying something like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await dbService.getData();
  var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
 for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

map['placeCol'] = result[i]['Name01']
...
}
```

So basically return data from db placeCol to be key and few other String in the List, like in example data.

With this approach:

```
 
Map<String, List> _map = {};

 for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

  _map[result[i]['placeCol']] = [result[i]['NameCol']];

}
```

I get this:

```
{1st : [Name 01]}
{1st : [Name 02]}
{1st : [Name 03]}
{1st : [Name 04]}
{1st : [Name 05]}
{2st : [Name 01]}
{2st : [Name 02]}
{2st : [Name 03]}
```

Instad of this:

```
{1st : [Name 01, Name02,Name03,Name04,Name05],
 2st : [Name 01, Name02,Name03]
}
```

Comment: Can you add rawData getting from db?

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating a map Directly from result map
So Something like this inside for loop

```
var map = result.elementAt(i)
```

And then you can use map to get data you want print it see how it looks to get a better idea of it's structure and use that to place it wherever you want

Comment: I edited my original question tnx for replaying.